# Mongoid Search Gem does not update keywords on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have an e-commerce application where I am using mongoid search to search through an order and its user association. Here are my models.

```
order.rb

class Order
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Search

   belongs_to :user

   search_in user: %i[first_name last_name email_address]
end

user.rb

class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Search

   has_many :orders

   search_in :email_address, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Basically the end goal of using search is to find a User's order by a users first name, last name, and email address. On initial pass, I can create an user and order and the `keywords` that mongoid uses to search get populated.

However, if I update a user's first name, last name, or email address, the keywords for `Order` doesnt get updated. Hence the search breaks and the accuracy decreases.

According to the documentation, I can do the following command `rake mongoid_search:index` and the keywords will be populated with the correct ones once more.

However, in production I can't run this command everytime something changes. I need it to update automatically. Is there something that I'm doing wrong where if I update assocciated objects the keywords won't change?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid_search/blob/master/lib/mongoid_search/mongoid_search.rb), you should be able to save the models that are affected (e.g. after changing a user, find & save all of their orders)  and the keywords will be updated automatically.